# VPN options in Vagrant

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, vagrant

At work I am able to spin up a Vagrant machine with public dhcp network and the dhcp server registers it's hostname on the internal DNS enabling me to share dev sites with nice urls. When at home I can vpn into office. What I really would like is to be able to spin up a vagrant machine at home and it get it's IP from the office DHCP server and hence register its host name on the office lan dns. I have tried to bridge to my home pc vpn interface but this didn't work - reading up I don't think this is possible. Is there any way achieve this goal? I am using virtual box but would be prepared to go to VMware fusion if needed.

Thanks for any help.